# environment variable other user

Tags: vbscript, environment-variables

I'm trying to set a environment variable for a user xy.
How can I do this in a visual basic script?

This is what I have:

```
Dim objShell As Object
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Environment("user")("TEST") = "12345"
```

In this way I can set a environment variable for the logged in user.
But how can I set a environment variable for an other user xy?

Markus

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change environment variables for other users you either have to run your code in their context (with `runas`) or change the variables in the registry. For the latter you have to load the user hive from the `ntuser.dat` in the user's profile:

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.Run "%COMSPEC% /c reg load HKU\Temp C:\Users\foo\ntuser.dat", 0, True
```

After the hive was loaded you can manipulate the environment subkey:

```
sh.RegWrite "HKEY_USERS\Temp\Environment\TEST", "12345", "REG_SZ"
```

Unload the hive after you've finished and you're done:

```
sh.Run "%COMSPEC% /c reg unload HKU\Temp", 0, True
```

Comment: Note that loading the user's hive will only work if the user isn't currently logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Only the system environment is available tot other users.

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
Set wshSystemEnv = wshShell.Environment( "SYSTEM" )
WScript.Echo "SYSTEM:  TEMP=" & wshSystemEnv( "TEMP" )
```